# jenkins email compressed artifacts

Tags: email, jenkins, artifacts

Is there a way to email the artifact compressed (zip).
I have a tool that generates a html report so there is the html file and a sub-folder with icons, xml etc. 
Using the compressed archive would allow to keep the folder structure inside the zip

a solution I see would be a post build task to just zip the archive folder using ant.

I am just wondering if I do not miss a very obvious better way to do it

thanks

Answer (score 5):

Well, there are couple of ways to achieve what you need:

1. Create a zip file and send it over

   [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) has an option to include any file from the workspace as an attachment of the email notification being sent to an email address provided or list of email addresses.
2. Using Email-ext plugin [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) one can send the file as part of the notification email

   There is almost no limit on how the plugin can be used since it provides scripting mechanism to build the recipients list and the content of the email. One can easily include the generated HTML file as a part of the body of the email and attach all of the necessary resources to the email itself. It's way more complicated approach, but the result should be glamorous.
3. Use the [HTML Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) to publish the reports locally (on Jenkins page) and send the link to either the build page or to specific location in the email.

   Be careful - depending on your data retention for the builds those pages might be deleted during the process of cleaning up old builds.
4. Create the zip/other package and deploy it to an external server/location using any of the [Artifact uploaders plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins#Plugins-Artifactuploaders) and include a link to that location in your email.

   Personally I would use my Maven repository to store that file. In that case you don't even have to use any of those plugins - just use the Maven publishing capabilities to upload the artifact and just use that location in your email.

Hope one of those ways will work for you...